# Building SQL from multiple combinations of query parameters

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, api

I have a node.js/express.js based REST application. In one GET service I am querying data based on different set of request parameters. I am looking for a better way to implement it.

```
function handleGet(connection,req,res) {

var sql = 'SELECT id, name, age, rent, marks FROM student WHERE class = 10';

if (req.param('minAge') && req.param('maxAge')) {
    sql = sql + ' AND age BETWEEN ' + connection.escape(req.param('minAge')) + ' AND ' + connection.escape(req.param('maxAge'));
}

if (req.param('minRent') && req.param('maxRent')) {
    sql =sql + ' AND rent BETWEEN ' + connection.escape(req.param('minRent')) 
        + ' AND ' + connection.escape(req.param('maxRent'));
};

if (req.param('marks')) {
    sql = sql + ' AND marks >= ' + connection.escape(req.param('marks'));
};

};



var limit = ('undefined' === typeof req.params.limit) ? 20: req.params.limit;

connection.query(sql + ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ' + limit, function handleSql(err, rows){
        if (err){ logAndRespond(err,res); return; }
        if (rows.length === 0){ res.send(204); return; }
        res.json(200, {'students':rows});
        connection.release();
});
}
```

Data can be queried by passing difference combination request parameters. Can anyone please suggest any better (reusable, abstract, robust) way of doing it? I was wondering if I can create a module for building query. Something like setting all param values in the module and let the module validate and construct the query.

Comment: Most I've seen are similar to yours, they just begin with select * from <table> WHERE 1 = 1 .... and class = 10.... etc.  Also remember to use parameterized queries to protect against injection.

Comment: Take a loot at [squel.js SQL query builder](https://hiddentao.github.io/squel/) for Node.js.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182652/javascript-query-selectors-dsl-as-an-independent-library

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dynamic string concatenation, you can do a logic trick. I'm going to use named sql placeholders for clarity. You'll obviously need to implement the code, I'm just giving you the idea.

```
select a
     , b
     , c
  from someTbl
 where (:PMaxAge  is null or maxAge <= :PMaxAge)
   and (:PMinRent is null or rent   >= :PMinRent)
   and (:PMaxRent is null or rent   <= :PMaxRent)
   -- etc ...
```

You may need to check for an empty string instead of checking for null to detect when a param was omitted depending on you implementation, but you get the point - let each criteria be satisfied if the param is missing.

Answer (score 2):

As @200_success suggested, don't use the keyword `BETWEEN` in SQL, [the result set can be unpredictable due to it](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx), especially with `DATE` or `DATETIME` data. Mathematical operators `> < =` are better.

You could significantly simplify your SQL-related code by *not* concatenating it with your Javascript code. Instead, I suggest to create a stored `PROCEDURE` in SQL and just pass parameters to it to get your result set. This will also improve performance. Here is an example (hint: this needs executed only once, after that it is stored):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_getStudent
    @class INT = 10,
    @minAge INT,
    @maxAge INT,
    @minRent DECIMAL(6,2),
    @maxRent DECIMAL(6,2),
    @marks -- it is not clear what type these would be
AS
-- procedure usp_getStudent starts here
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT id, name, age, rent, marks 
FROM student
WHERE
-- class filter
    class = @class
-- age filter
AND
    (
    age >= @minAge
    OR @minAge ISNULL
    )
AND
    (
    age <= @maxAge
    OR @maxAge ISNULL
    )
-- rent filter
AND
    (
    rent >= @minRent
    OR @minAge ISNULL
    )
AND
    (
    rent <= @maxRent
    OR @maxAge ISNULL
    )
-- marks filter
AND
    marks -- insert some condition here
;
GO
```

Then from Javascript all you need to do, instead of all this concatenating SQL code, is this:

```
sql = sql 'CALL usp_getStudent (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6);'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's counterintuitive that *both* `minAge` and `maxAge` have to be specified to have any effect.  Why shouldn't the criteria work independently?  Simplifying your code would also make your API less surprising.  Don't bother with `BETWEEN ? AND ?`; go with separate `>=` and `<=` criteria instead.  (Your goal is to produce the most predictable SQL query, not necessarily the prettiest.)

If possible, I'd rename the `marks` parameter to `minMarks`.  Then your code can be more regular.  (In fact, you would get `maxMarks` handling for free.)

```
var criteria = ['class = 10'];

var attrs = ['Age', 'Rent', 'Marks'];
attrs.forEach(function(attr) {
    if (req.param('min' + attr)) {
        criteria.push(attr.toLowerCase() + ' >= ' + connection.escape(req.param('min' + attr)));
    }
    if (req.param('max' + attr)) {
        criteria.push(attr.toLowerCase() + ' <= ' + connection.escape(req.param('max' + attr)));
    }
});

var limit = ('undefined' === typeof req.params.limit) ? 20 : req.param('limit');
var sql = 'SELECT id, name, age, rent, marks FROM student WHERE ' +
    attrs.join(' AND ') +
    ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ' + limit;
```